# Why do multiple inserts in a stored procedure not work with PyODBC?

Tags: sql-server, python-2.7, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

My database is Azure Data Warehouse. My Python version is Python 2.7 and I am using PyODBC to call SQL statements and stored procedures against the database.

The script can connect and does execute stored procs and SQL fine against the server. However, I have one stored proc with no parameters that is simply doing something similar to below from an external table (Azure BLOB):

```
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.Table1;
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.Table2;
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.Table3;

INSERT INTO dbo.Table1
SELECT * FROM ext.Table1;

INSERT INTO dbo.Table2
SELECT * FROM ext.Table2;

Etc...
```

All Truncate statements succeed. Inserts work on first table. The script ends without doing inserts on the other tables. Running the stored proc with the same user in SSMS shows it works fine. Yet, PyODBC does not seem to complete the stored proc without any errors or warnings. It looks to work, but doesn't.

The only thing I can think of is the fact this is off External Tables and the External Tables do have dirty reads that are sent to the client as rejected messages. PyODBC may be failing silently because of the rejected messages returned back to the API.

Comment: Confirmed, the "rejected from external table" messages is causing PyODBC to die. It's returning multiple messages back to PyODBC even if the Stored Proc is successful. Need to find out how I can make PyODBC work with the notion that the server will send multiple failed row messages that are technically headers.

Comment: Also being discussed on GitHub [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/634).

Comment: Thanks, I posted that report. Will leave this open just in case the resolution is just updating to latest version of PyODBC. Be good to have a log of it on stack just in case others run into that with Azure DW/Polybase.